# Windows 10 / Linux dual boot broken

Tags: linux, windows-10, multi-boot

I recently (a week ago) dual booted my Windows 10 installation with Pop! OS 19.04 because I wanted to test it out. I really liked it, and because I just had games on my Windows 10 installation, I wiped both of my drives (128GB SSD, 1.5TB HDD) and installed Pop! OS 19.04 on the SSD. After a few hours, it started freezing randomly for a few seconds, sometimes it would freeze for so long that I hat to manually shut the system off. I then tried Linux Mint, but that was the same story.

Now today, I decided to reinstall Windows 10, but it freezed as well! With Linux, I thought it might just be bad compatability or something, but it cleary isn't. Even unplugging my HDD wouldn't work. I reinstalled Windows a few times and ran different hardware tests:

- The Windows memory test didn't find any issues
- My SSD sectors are completely fine according to the Macrorit Disk Scanner
- Prime95 found a hardware failure without any specifications

I have an old computer standing around and I tried replacing my two 4GB memory modules with two 2GB modules from that PC, but Windows crashed at the login screen.

Here is a list with current symptoms of Windows:

- After a few minutes, every window I open is transparent apart from the border
- It sometimes randomly freezes and not even my keyboard lights react anymore

Here is a list of my PC specs:

- CPU: AMD fx-6300
- GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 2GB VRAM
- Motherboard: BIOSTAR A960D+ V2
- RAM: 8GB (2x4GB, there's a sticker on the module that says it's for AMD)
- PSU: POWER LC420H-12

I didn't build this PC myself which is why you might have never heard of those brands before. I hope you can help me!

Comment: If my memory serves me, Prime95 is a CPU test, so it sounds like your issue is connected to your processor.

Comment: Any ideas on what I could change? Or would I have to buy a new one?

Comment: Before you attempt to replace a processor that old, I/O errors, could also explain the error.  I would disconnect your mechanical HDD, as that is the most likely candidate, to cause the behavior you describe.  However, without more information on the Prime95 failure, it's difficult to rule out the processor.  I would make sure the dust bunnies suffer an extinction level event within your machine.

Comment: The AMD FX line of processors is very ancient compared to today’s standards for CPUs. It could also be your GPU itself, because your display is the only problem. Possibly your CPU is bottlenecking, so a new one would be a better choice.

Comment: I put my drives and my GPU in another system and they're working just fine. I'll contact the vendor because I realized that I still have half a year of warranty left.